# Strange Huawei Exception

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I see strange exception in flurry. This Exception appears only on Huawei devices with android 5.1 and 5.1.1. I can't reproduce it. May be somebody know what this exception mean? And how i can reproduce it?

```
UnknownException
at res.content.android.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:65)
at res.content.android.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:458)
at res.content.android.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:1029)
at res.content.android.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:188)
at widget.android.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1078)
at widget.android.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:680)
at widget.v7.support.android.AppCompatTextView.<init>(62)
at widget.v7.support.android.AppCompatTextView.<init>(58)
at app.v7.support.android.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(103)
at app.v7.support.android.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(1021)
at app.v7.support.android.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(1080)
at view.v4.support.android.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(47)
at view.android.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:744)
at view.android.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:501)
at view.android.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:425)
at view.android.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:368)
at com.huawei.android.hwcontrol.HwEditor$HwActionPopupWindow.initContentView(HwEditor.java:929)
at widget.android.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2308)
at widget.android.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3023)
at com.huawei.android.hwcontrol.HwEditor$HwActionPopupWindow.<init>(HwEditor.java:879)
at com.huawei.android.hwcontrol.HwEditor.createActionPopupWindow(HwEditor.java:186)
at widget.android.Editor$HandleView.showActionPopupWindow(Editor.java:3460)
at widget.android.Editor$InsertionHandleView.show(Editor.java:3749)
at widget.android.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.show(Editor.java:4015)
at widget.android.Editor.showInsertionController(Editor.java:4755)
at com.huawei.android.hwcontrol.HwEditor.showInsertionController(HwEditor.java:212)
at com.huawei.android.hwcontrol.HwEditor.onTouchUpEvent(HwEditor.java:203)
at widget.android.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:8445)
at view.android.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8624)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at impl.policy.internal.android.com.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2503)
at impl.policy.internal.android.com.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1813)
at app.android.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2827)
at view.v7.support.android.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(71)
at view.v7.support.android.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(71)
at impl.policy.internal.android.com.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2464)
at view.android.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8830)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4799)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4657)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4219)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4185)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4322)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4193)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4379)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4219)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4185)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4193)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6608)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6582)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6535)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6778)
at view.android.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
at os.android.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at os.android.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:148)
at os.android.Looper.loop(Looper.java:151)
at app.android.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5929)
at reflect.lang.java.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at reflect.lang.java.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at os.internal.android.com.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:987)
at os.internal.android.com.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
view.android.InflateException: (Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class TextView)
at view.android.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at view.android.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:501)
at view.android.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:425)
at view.android.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:368)
at com.huawei.android.hwcontrol.HwEditor$HwActionPopupWindow.initContentView(HwEditor.java:929)
at widget.android.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2308)
at widget.android.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3023)
at com.huawei.android.hwcontrol.HwEditor$HwActionPopupWindow.<init>(HwEditor.java:879)
at com.huawei.android.hwcontrol.HwEditor.createActionPopupWindow(HwEditor.java:186)
at widget.android.Editor$HandleView.showActionPopupWindow(Editor.java:3460)
at widget.android.Editor$InsertionHandleView.show(Editor.java:3749)
at widget.android.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.show(Editor.java:4015)
at widget.android.Editor.showInsertionController(Editor.java:4755)
at com.huawei.android.hwcontrol.HwEditor.showInsertionController(HwEditor.java:212)
at com.huawei.android.hwcontrol.HwEditor.onTouchUpEvent(HwEditor.java:203)
at widget.android.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:8445)
at view.android.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8624)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2521)
at view.android.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
at impl.policy.internal.android.com.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2503)
at impl.policy.internal.android.com.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1813)
at app.android.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2827)
at view.v7.support.android.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(71)
at view.v7.support.android.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(71)
at impl.policy.internal.android.com.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2464)
at view.android.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8830)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4799)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4657)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4219)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4185)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4322)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4193)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4379)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4219)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4185)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4193)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6608)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6582)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6535)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6778)
at view.android.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
at os.android.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at os.android.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:148)
at os.android.Looper.loop(Looper.java:151)
at app.android.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5929)
at reflect.lang.java.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at reflect.lang.java.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at os.internal.android.com.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:987)
at os.internal.android.com.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
```

Comment: Could you fix it man? I am having the same issue right now and I need to solve it too :(

Comment: Unfortunately but no.